# sqlite3 table with limited max lines (by choice) efficiency

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite

I am storing data on an interval basis (gps location) and I dont want the DB to swell up so I defined a MAX number of lines it can go up to and then it simply deletes the oldest line every time I insert a new one.

Now a database expert looked at my code and he says its way not efficient because deleting a row from the database is the most time/memory/procedures consuming action and I should avoid it at all cost.

He says I should instead, run-over the oldest line (update) after I reach MAX.
(so it goes top to bottom every time)

That means I need to save a separate "header" table to save my current pointer to the oldest line and update it on every insert (i don't want to lose it if the app crashes) .. 
does it really more efficient ? any other ways to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Rather than delete/update on insert, why don't you just run a job at a set interval and/or under certain conditions to delete the oldest rows? So, if your arbitrary max is currently 1,000,000 rows, why don't you just set a job to delete the oldest 100,000 rows once the count is >= 1,100,000?

Comment: @gangreen It is a better implement then my original (which I already considered) but it still contradicts what the db expert says that its the delete itself that is not efficient - not the big amount of actions I preform so in his opinion deleting 100,000 still more expensive then saving a pointer and updating the oldest one every time..

Comment: I'm not sure I would call myself an expert, but I think your expert is wrong. An insert doesn't requiring using a `WHERE` clause to find the row you need, then update it. If your update doesn't require updating any indexes, that could be cheaper than an insert that does require it. If your app receives a lot of new data, I think it would be cheaper to run a single delete statement and append the 100,000 records, if it receives data infrequently, you can probably get away with updating each line - bottom line, you should probably set performance limits and then do some benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning your database table into a ring buffer is silly.
If you really want to use this approach...

- Don't use a database just use a data file and IO
- - In your data file each record will be a fixed size
- - - [Time Stamp][Latitude][Longitude]
- - - You can use string formatted or binary representations of your data it doesn't matter as long as they are fixed size.

----------gps.dat----------

```
[Ring Pointer]
[Time Stamp][Latitude][Longitude]
[Time Stamp][Latitude][Longitude]
...
[Time Stamp][Latitude][Longitude]
```

- Ring Pointer is the binary representation of a long integer
- When you first create the file you'll set its size to the size of an LONG_INTEGER_SIZE + (MAX_RECORDS * RECORD_SIZE)

When you want to add a record:

- Read [Ring Pointer] from the beginning of the file
- Write [Ring Pointer] + 1 to the beginning of the file (so people don't get confused keep the [Ring Pointer] variable the same just write the new value back to the file)
- Go to location LONG_INTEGER_SIZE + (([Ring Pointer] % MAX_RECORDS) * RECORD_SIZE)
- Write your new record at that location

Comment: Still not sure which way we're going to go with this (we might want future features that query the table in a way that will make it entangling to use txt file table) but that's a great approach IMO and should be super efficient and cheap. thanks for the detailed explanation.